# Snakemake-Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files

Tags: snakemake

I'm kinda new at snakemake and I'm trying to understand how it works.
I tried to pull a simple snakefile

```
from snakemake.utils import min_version
min_version("5.3.0")
max_reads: 250000
sra_id: ["SRR1187735"]
rule all:
    input:
        "DATA/{sra_id}.fastq.gz"
    
rule prefetch:
    output:
        "DATA/{sra_id}.fastq.gz"
    params:
        max_reads = "max_reads"
    version: "1.0"
    shell:
        "conda activate sra-tools-2.10.1 " 
        "&& "
        "fastq-dump {wildcards.sra_id} -X {params.max_reads} --readids \
            --dumpbase --skip-technical --gzip -Z > {output} "
        "&& "
        "conda deactivate "
```

But I'm getting this error :

> WildcardError in line 5 of /save_home/skastalli/test_rule/Snakefile:
> Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
> 'sra_id'

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of your rules should be generalizable and include wildcards, so prefetch is correct.  At some point you *have* to ask for a specific file for snakemake to try and generate.  This can occur in several spots of the workflow, but at least the rule all needs to ask for specific files.  Based on your preamble, I think the input of your rule all should be:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("DATA/{sra_id}.fastq.gz", sra_id=sra_id)
```

Also, because snakemake runs in debug mode for shell, you don't need the `&&` in the shell directive and can just use newlines instead.  Personal preference though.